# How to activate workbook exported from SAP?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, activation

I have a macro to process data from SAP.

When the workbook from SAP appears I am not able to activate it via VBA code below.

Even `Workbooks("export.xlsx").activate` does not work.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nFBL3N"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_SD_SAKNR_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "179811"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text = "431311"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radX_AISEL").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-LOW").Text = "01.03.2020"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").Text = "31.03.2020"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[16]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_%_SUB%_CONTAINER:SAPLSSEL:2001/ssubSUBSCREEN_CONTAINER2:SAPLSSEL:2000/ssubSUBSCREEN_CONTAINER:SAPLSSEL:1106/ctxt%%DYN009-LOW").Text = "L6"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_%_SUB%_CONTAINER:SAPLSSEL:2001/ssubSUBSCREEN_CONTAINER2:SAPLSSEL:2000/ssubSUBSCREEN_CONTAINER:SAPLSSEL:1106/ctxt%%DYN009-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_%_SUB%_CONTAINER:SAPLSSEL:2001/ssubSUBSCREEN_CONTAINER2:SAPLSSEL:2000/ssubSUBSCREEN_CONTAINER:SAPLSSEL:1106/ctxt%%DYN009-LOW").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

Set session = Nothing
Set Connection = Nothing
Set SapGuiAuto = Nothing
Set WScript = Nothing
Set Application = Nothing

Dim wb As Workbook
Windows("export.XLSX").Activate
```

Comment: Is the exported Workbook open? If not, do you know where is it created? If yes, you must open it using the `Workbooks.Open("Download path" & "\" & "export.xlsx"`.

Comment: Hi, it is already open

Comment: Are you sure? Is it open in the same Excel session? You can iterate between the existing workbooks to check that: `Dim wb as Workbook` followed by `For Each wb in Workbooks`     `If UCase(wb.Name) = "EXPORT.XLSX" Then wb.Activate: Exit For`  `Next`.

Comment: You say "when workbook from sap appears", do you mean SAP has first created an Excel file on the desktop, and SAP starts automatically Excel and the workbook is opened automatically? And you want to get a handle to this workbook? Something like `set excel = GetObject(,"excel.application"), set wb = excel.workbooks("export.XLSX")`?

Comment: Hi, Yes it creates it automatically, and I would like to activate it and save as something else e.g. save it on c disc

Comment: Did you try finding it by iteration, as I suggested? Maybe, it is open in another Excel Session. What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: it seems that macro cannot see that workbook , how to find that session ? excel 2016

Comment: I will prepare an answer. I need to look in my old interesting pieces of code collection...

Comment: Posted the answer. Please, test it and let me know if it worked as you need. Take care of the places where the first pieces of code must be placed and the way of function calling, mainly the necessary declarations to be used. In fact, you can copy all the code, declarations included, instead of your last code line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check the existence of the workbook in all open Excel sessions, please use the next code, as I will explain

Firstly copy the next code on top of your module (in the declarations part):

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
#End If
```

Then, use the next function to be called from your existing code (instead of `Windows("export.XLSX").Activate`):

```
Private Function GetExcelSes() As Collection
    Dim g&(0 To 3), ppv As Object, hWnd, hWnd2, hWnd3
    g(0) = &H20400: g(1) = &H0
    g(2) = &HC0:    g(3) = &H46000000

    Dim AlreadyThere As Boolean, Xl As Application
    Set GetExcelSes = New Collection
    Do
        hWnd = FindWindowExA(0, hWnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        If hWnd = 0 Then Exit Do
        hWnd2 = FindWindowExA(hWnd, 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
        hWnd3 = FindWindowExA(hWnd2, 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWnd3, &HFFFFFFF0, g(0), ppv) = 0 Then
            AlreadyThere = False
            For Each Xl In GetExcelSes
                If Xl Is ppv.Application Then
                    AlreadyThere = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not AlreadyThere Then
                GetExcelSes.aDD ppv.Application
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

The above function can be called as in the following example (use it like it is instead of your last code line). The declarations are important:

```
Sub TestSaveAWbFromAllSess()
   Dim Ex As Collection, El As Variant
   Dim wb As Workbook, expWb As Workbook
   Set Ex = GetExcelSes

   For Each El In Ex
        For Each wb In El.Workbooks
            Debug.Print wb.Name 'just to see all open wb names, confirming that the function works...
            If UCase(wb.Name) = "EXPORT.XLSX" Then
                Set expWb = wb
                'Do here whatever you need with the found workbook. For instance:
                expWb.SaveCopyAs fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\TestSAPExport.XLSX"
            End If
        Next
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: great really thank you , it worked for me :) thank you again

Comment: @RBL219: Glad I could help! Now you can comment or delete `Debug.Print wb.Name` line... And, voting the code up, too, did not kill anybody, from what I know. Of course, only if you liked it... :)